# A fork() output

Tags: c, fork

I have the following code:

```
int main(){
  if (fork() + fork())
     printf("Boom!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why this code prints the message 3 times.

Can someone explain me?

Comment: How many times do you think it should print it?

Comment: You have the main process that duplicates itself twice. Shouldn't it be clear?

Comment: The second fork() confuses me. after this we have 4 processes? and only 2 have 0 as id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fork returns non-zero when for the parent process and zero for the child process.

So the parent proces forks, creating one child process (`fork1`). This child process will fork again (it will execute the second fork) (`fork2`). Creating a second child process. Then the parent process will fork on the second fork call, creating a third process (`fork3`). So we will get a tree structure like this:

```
           Parent
  fork1            fork3
       fork2
```

Now note that for a child process the values of all calls executed before the fork are inherited from the parent process. If we use this we get:

- `Parent` will have a non-zero return value, because both `fork()` calls returns a non-zero value
- `fork1` will have a non-zero return value, because the last fork returns a non-zero value
- `fork2` will have a zero return value, because the first fork is zero (this is inherited from `fork1`) and the second fork will also return zero (`fork2` is created in the second fork).
- `fork3` will have a non-zero return value, because it inherits the first fork value from the `Parent`.

When the `fork() + fork()` is non zero the if will be executed. Thus 3 times boom!.

Comment: Are you sure that zero is the return value for the parent and non-zero is the child?
In the    man it was vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

Make the following test :

```
int main() {
    pidsum = fork() + fork();
    printf("%d", pidsum);
}
```

Comment: That 4 threads are created.
0 for parent.
> 1 for 3 childs.
The 3 childs have diferent PIDs.